# Android "singleTask" activity creates new instance of the Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two different application called **App A** and **App B**.

- App A : ActivityA with launch mode -> "singleTask"
- App B : ActivityB with launch mode -> "singleInstance"

Steps:

1. Open App A which will open ActivityA, ActivityStack : **ActivityA**
2. Starting App B with startActivityForResult(), ActivityStack : **ActivityA > ActivityB**
3. Open ActivityA via Intent from Activity B , ActivityStack : **ActivityA > ActivityB > ActivityA**

As you can see the activity stack, It creates new instance of the Activity A instead of returning to the same instance of the ActivityA by calling **onNewIntent()** method.

I am not sure, is this because of Activity started for result.? Please help to provide proper solution in this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: I think activity never has any instance. 
It is managed by the android lifecycle.

Comment: try to add this intent filter in your ActivityB intent "flag_activity_reorder_to_front"

Comment: I've answered your question. But what are you trying to do? I'm sure there are simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: @David Wasser: When i send Open ActivityA via Intent from Activity B, i want the same ActivityA instance(which started ActivityB) to be called via onNewIntent() instead of creating new instance. Could you help me with that.

Comment: you could have A call B using `startActivityForResult()`. This won't work if you are using special launch modes (singleInstance or singleTask). Why are you using special launch modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a `singleTask` `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()`. If you launch an `Activity` and expect a result returned, then the target `Activity` **must be launched in the same task**. Due to this, Android is ignoring the `singleTask` launch mode when you call `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Thanks @David Wasser. Make sense. If you have started an Activity for result then android automatically ignore the "singleTask".